# Create a procedure that acts like an object - Scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to create a procedure that would act as an object class. Such as having its own attribute and methods. I am trying to create a make-list procedure that would be bound to a variable (define L1 (make-list)), however I am having issue with implementing the the attribute local-list which is the stored list in the bounded to the variable L1. My issue that no matter how I changed (define local-list '(1 2 3 4)) - I always get Empty on my print-list procedure

```
  (define (make-list)
    ;;Helper procedures
    (define (print-list list)
      (if (eq? list '())
        (display "Empty")
        (begin (car list)
          (print-list (cdr list)))))
    (begin
      (define local-list '(1 2 3 4))
      (lambda (x)
        (cond 
          ((eq? x 'size)
           (begin 
             (display "L1: ")
             (newline)
             (local-list)
             (print-list (local-list))))
           (else #f)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close

```
(define (make-list)

  ;;Helper procedures
  (define (print-list list)
    (if (eq? list '())
        (display "Empty")
        (begin (displayln (car list)) ; <-display missing
               (print-list (cdr list)))))
  ; no begin here
  (define local-list '(1 2 3 4))

  (lambda (x)
    (cond 
      ((eq? x 'size)
       (begin 
         (display "L1: ")
         (newline)
         (print-list local-list))) ; <- no call to local-list (2x)
      (else #f))))
```

Testing

```
> (define L1 (make-list))
> (L1 'size)
L1: 
1
2
3
4
Empty
>
```